# DOM.getElementById always NULL?

Tags: gwt

I am getting `java.lang.AssertionError: null` error for this code:

```
usernameTextBox = TextBox.wrap(DOM.getElementById("username"));
passwordTextBox = TextBox.wrap(DOM.getElementById("password"));
```

Here's my code for the GWT HTML file which has the `nocache.js`:

http://pastebin.com/QeSuZivJ

EDIT:

Also have tried:

```
Document.get().getElementById("username") 
Document.get().getElementById("password")
```

Still getting NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('username');
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: Cool. Thanks. It works now, however I had to change the <input> from the html from type="password" to <input id="password" type="text">

Comment: Where does he get the `document` instance? Also, single quotes are used for chars, strings use double quotes. Your code does not compile. OP had problems accessing the password box because javascript can not access input boxes of password type.

Comment: Hmm, I just realized that you wrote javascript, while OP writes in Java/GWT.

Comment: Oops... you are right, my bad. Seems like Xybrek figured it out on his own though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  `RootPanel.get("nameFieldContainer").getElement();`